# Compute a measure of "near multiplicity" from a list of noisy values

Tags: python, statistics

## Question

Let us say I've got a list of values which have a common multiple greater than 1. For example, let us take the multiple to be 3 and form a collection of multiples of this value:

```
harmonicList = [3,6,6,3,3,9,27,3,15,18,9]
```

Now I add some noise:

```
harmonicList = [ v + (random() * 2 - 1 ) * 0.1 for v in harmonicList]
```

I'm searching for an algorithm that will return a number near 1.0 when the items in the list are near to being multiples of a common value but near 0.0 when the numbers are not near to being multiples -- such as, for example when the list is a collection of prime numbers.

Is there such a measure of "near multiplicity"?

## Why I want to solve this problem

I'm currently trying to detect Chessboard in a screenshot using Hough Transform. Sometimes the case is ideal, and it works very well :

[image]

But sometimes not :
[image]

I would like to detect the cases where there is a lot of aberrations. Thus, my idea is to compute the intersections of the lines detected, and create a collection of length  (only if the lines where horizontal or vertical). If the detection was good, I know that there will be a great "harmonicity" inside this collection I can then use that algorithm and a threshold.

I know there is probably a better method to detect a chessboard. Maybe that this one is even stupid but that how comes the problem and I find it interesting.

Comment: I've changed the language a bit. Please check to make sure I haven't changed your intent.

Comment: thank you it's a lot better :D

Comment: Are harmonics expected to be integer values, or something like [2.5, 6.25, 7.5, 12.5] could also be expected?

Comment: float value could also be expected

Comment: This looks like a numeric algorithm problem. I'd try asking on mathoverflow.com.

Comment: I was hesitating to do so but the last time I asked a question on it I just had the time to go get a coffee and it was already downvoted at -7 : D but yes this is definitly a numeric algorithm problem. I will post the same question and see

Comment: [Question asked on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2650706/1140)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Python implementation of [Robert Dodier's maximum log-likelihood
idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2650812/1140). I added a scoring
function, `score` -- not the one Robert Dodier describes in his answer --
but rather just a sum of squares of residuals (`x` minus its closest
multiple). To make the score go from 0 to 1, I take the exponential of the
negative of this sum of squares:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


primes = np.array([2,  3,  5,  7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43,
                   47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97])

def harmonic(divisor, size=10):
    return np.random.randint(1, 10, size=size) * divisor

def prime_sample(size=10):
    return np.random.choice(primes, size=size)

def noisy(x, amount=0.1):
    return x + (np.random.random(size=len(x)) * 2 - 1) * amount

def prob(x, mean, sd):
    return stats.norm.pdf(x, loc=mean, scale=sd)

def score(x, multiplier, offset, kmax=20):
    k = np.arange(kmax)
    means = (k * multiplier + offset)[:, None]
    closest_multiple = (np.abs(x - means).argmin(axis=0)) * multiplier
    result = np.exp(-((x - closest_multiple)**2).sum())
    return result

def fit(x, multipliers, offsets, kmax=20, sd=0.2):
    "sd is the standard deviation of the noise"
    k = np.arange(kmax)
    M, O, K = np.meshgrid(multipliers, offsets, k, indexing='ij')
    means = (K * M + O)[..., None]
    p = prob(x, means, sd)
    # sum over the K axis, take the log, sum over x axis
    L = np.log(p.sum(axis=-2)).sum(axis=-1)
    # find the location of maximum log likelihood
    i, j = np.unravel_index(L.argmax(), L.shape)
    max_L = L[i, j]
    multiplier = multipliers[i]
    offset = offsets[j]
    return dict(loglikelihood=L, max_L=max_L,
                multiplier=multiplier, offset=offset,
                score=score(x, multiplier, offset, kmax))

multipliers = np.linspace(3, 10, 100)
offsets = np.linspace(-1.5, 1.5, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(multipliers, offsets, indexing='ij')
tests = [([12,  8, 28, 20, 32, 12, 28, 16,  4, 12], 1),
         ([3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 27, 54, 57], 0),
         (noisy(harmonic(3, size=20)), 1),
         (noisy(prime_sample()), 0)]

for x, expected in tests:
    result = fit(x, multipliers, offsets, kmax=20)
    Z = result['loglikelihood']
    plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
    plt.xlabel('multiplier')
    plt.ylabel('offset')
    plt.scatter(result['multiplier'], result['offset'], s=20, c='red')
    plt.title('score = {:g}, expected = {:g}'
              .format(result['score'], expected))
    plt.show()
```

For `x = [12, 8, 28, 20, 32, 12, 28, 16, 4, 12]`:

[image]
For `x = [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 27, 54, 57]`:
[image]

Comment: Very good, thanks for working on this problem. The likelihood-based approach is a generalization of least squares, but least squares is certainly sufficient for the problem that snoob dogg was working on.

Answer (score 0):

I am secretly hoping someone will come up with a better and more elegant solution, but the following snippet might at least give some inspiration:

```
for i in range(1,int(round(min(harmonicList)))+1): #makes no sense to look at bigger numbers
    temp_sum = 0
    for item in harmonicList:
        item = item % i
        temp_sum += min(item, i-item) #because noise can be either plus or minus
    if i == 1:
        comparator = temp_sum
    elif temp_sum == comparator:
        print(i, "is a common denominator")
#prints "3 is a common denominator"
```

In comparison:

```
primeList = [1,3,5,7,11,13,17]
```

Then running the same noise generator and the for loop, will result in nothing being printed at all.

```
for _ in range(1000):
    primeList = [1,3,5,7,11,13,17]
    primeList = [ v + (random() * 2 - 1 ) * 0.1 for v in primeList]
    for i in range(1,int(round(min(primeList)))+1):
        temp_sum = 0
        for item in primeList:
            item = item % i
            temp_sum += min(item, i-item)
        if i == 1:
            comparator = temp_sum
        elif temp_sum == comparator:
            print(i, "is a common denominator")
#No prints
```

Comment: Why do you need to do  `while item > i:` when `item % i` will always make item < i?

Comment: unfortunatly, it doesn't seems to work very well, I tested it by comparing with a prime number list also with a bit of noise and it got sometimes a better score : ( "harmonicList (3, 0.6170481134676646)  primeList (3, 0.6997208840623692)"

Comment: it is not a score .. probably should leave that out of the print. It was there out of curiosity how big the noise level was..But if it prints any number, it means that your divisor is exactly as good as dividing by 1. If you are working with integers, it should mean it is a common divisor.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clean (hopefully someone will improve) but this does the job:

```
from operator import itemgetter
def near_multiplicity(num_list):
    rounded_num_list = [round(num) for num in num_list]
    factors = {}
    for num in rounded_num_list:
        for factor in range(2, int(num)+1):
            if int(num) % factor == 0:
                factors[factor] = factors.get(factor, 0) + 1
    sorted_factors = sorted(factors.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    if sorted_factors[0][1] == 1:
        return 0
    best_factor = sorted_factors[0][0]
    noise = 0
    for num in num_list:
        distortion = num % best_factor
        noise += min(distortion, best_factor - distortion)
    average_noise = noise / len(num_list)
    return 1 - average_noise
```

Comment: Sorry but your function returns 1.0 for [3,5,7,11,13,27,54] which should be near from zero : (

Comment: Are you sure you did it right because I tried it with that list and it returned `0.4285714285714286` which is quite accurate as all of them are 1 away a multiple of 3 or a multiple of 3

Comment: yes sorry I forgot to use 'from __ future__ import division'